# Problem with saving binary format to Integer list

Tags: java, list

I have a problem with saving binary format to Integer list in Java. I have a pice of code:

```
while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println(line);
            Integer x = Integer.valueOf(line);
            msg.add(x);
            decoding(msgc);
            msg.clear();
        }
```

After this, I have error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0100001111100111"
```

All my actions are on Intiger list so I have to save to Integer. How can I solve this problem? I've tried everything. Thanks, and great a have day!

Comment: `integer.valueOf` waits for a decimal number but 0100001111100111 is too large for an int

Comment: @bruno Thanks! I created a 'for' loop that writes character by character and I used `Character.getNumericValue()`

Comment: you can also convert it by yourself

Comment: How about just `Integer.parseInt(bitString, 2);`  // takes a radix. or `Integer.valueOf(bitString,2);`

Answer (score 0):

you probably suppose 0100001111100111 will be read by `Integer.valueOf` as a binary value, but this is not the case and it considers it is a decimal value, the problem is that number is too large for an integer, so you have the exception.

Using `Long.valueOf` you will not have an exception but not the expected result

One way is to do the conversion by yourself, of course that supposes the number of digits it not too large even in binary